# dictionary key data line count

Tags: python, dictionary, line

Here I have a text file that looks like this:

```
34 56 54 45 54 4
76 65 56 54 45 2
76 56 54 34 23 1
```

and I'm trying to find a way to create a dictionary with the dictionary key
which is the line number and the value that corresponds to the number sequence on the line.
I try this :

```
d = {}
l = []
ctn = 0
with open('text.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        for c in line:
            ctn += 1 if c == '\n' else 0
        l.append(line.split())
for i in range(ctn):
    d[i] = l[i]
```

Is there a more effective way to achieve this?

Comment: With your solution you are not returning line 2 (3rd line)!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `enumerate` and a dictionary comprehension to do it in one line (well, two including opening the file):

```
with open('text.txt', 'r') as f:
    d = {i: line.split() for i, line in enumerate(f.read().splitlines())}
```

this returns:

```
{0: ['34', '56', '54', '45', '54', '4'], 1: ['76', '65', '56', '54', '45', '2'], 2: ['76', '56', '54', '34', '23', '1']}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use dictionary comprehension:

```
new_data = {i+1:map(int, a.strip('\n').split()) for i, a in enumerate(open('text.txt'))}
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need the list:

```
d = {}
with open('text.txt', 'r') as f:
    i = 0
    for line in f:
        i += 1
        d[i] = line.split()
print(d)
```